# Preserve Empty Directories in a Gem Build

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a Gem I'm developing - My Gemspecs builds the files for the gem from git:

```
spec.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```

The Gem itself has an empty directory in the lib folder, which i've added a .keep to preserve via git

```
my_gem/
  - lib/
    - some_empty_folder/
      - .keep
```

But when I install the gem to my system I see that `some_empty_folder` gets removed.

According to specification refrence: http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files

> files
>
> Files included in this gem. You cannot append to this accessor, you
>   must assign to it.
>   Only add files you can require to this list, not directories, etc.
>   Directories are automatically stripped from this list when building a
>   gem, other non-files cause an error.

I was hoping the `.keep` file would preserve this empty structure, but I've hacked around it by adding an empty `.rb` file. What is the best way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the .keep, you could instead add a .gitignore to the empty folder.

```
# Ignore all items in this directory
*
# Except this .gitignore file
!.gitignore
```

This will always preserve that folder as an empty structure.